# Android Emulator stop working after update to 31.2.6 [M1/Apple Silicon]

Tags: android, android-emulator, apple-m1

After updating Android emulator to `31.2.6` today, emulator stop working. It says `Connecting to the Emulator` and process of `qemu-system-aarch64` is become unresponsive

It worked well on previous version of emulator, which I downloaded with Arctic Fox, but can't rollback it

AS version: Bumblebee 2021.1.1 (downloaded it using Toolbox app)

macOS: Big Sur 11.6

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is two workarounds I've found for now:

1. Try to close the process of `qemu-system-aarch64` in Monitor System, **not force close**. When you click close emulator will prompt about saving state and two buttons `Yes/No`. Ignore them and click close icon in the left corner, then emulator start working correctly. Tried it at least once and it worked.
2. Because it's **Bumblebee**, emulator open inside AS by default. To turn off it, open:

> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator

And uncheck checkbox as in the image below

[image]

Then emulator will work correctly

Anyway, I think it's bug of `31.2.6`

Comment: it worked for once but now when I launch emulator again, I can only see the emulator icon in the doc but clicking on it doesn't reveal emulator, tried multiple times, even the prompt is not coming after closing emulator from activity monitor, any help?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216675028

Problem is identified and solved. Hope an update is available shortly.

Comment: New version(31.2.7) is released in SDK manager, which fixes the bug. Here is the actual link 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_aarch64-8135630.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:
On Device Manager open dropdown menu near your device and choose "Cold Boot Now"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

how frustrating this is. My solution was to delete all (3) emulators and reinstall. I've only reinstalled one and I upped the APK level by one to Pixel3a XL API 31, up from 30. Emulator, at least initially, is working OK. The whole process has now taken a couple of hours.